A continuous function can be bounded from above by a smooth 'adapted' function?
Consider a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. Is there a standard strategy that produces a function $g\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$, such that

$f(t)\le g(t)$ $\forall t$;

$g(t)$ can be defined only by $\{f(s)\}_{s\le t}$.


A similar $g $ function allows to produce a smooth upper bound to the function $t\to max_{x \in [0,1]}h(x,t)$, where $h\in C^{\infty}([0,1]\times \mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}_+)$.
I highlight that the second requirement is related to probabilistic concepts such as adaptability.
Thank you in advance for any hint!

What do you mean by the second condition? do you mean $g(t)\in {f(s) \mid s\leq t}$?

I mean that  $g(t)$ can be built only using the past history of $f$, i.e. $f(s)$ for all $s\le t$.  I don't think that imposing $g(t)=f(r)$ for some $r\le t$ can produce a smooth function.

I see, thanks for clarifying.

I'll interpret the word strategy as mapping, so we are basically interested in the existence of a monotone (with respect to pointwise ordering) mapping $F$ from the continuous functions to the smooth functions with the property that for all continuous $f$ and $g$ and for all real $a,$ if $f\equiv g$ on $x\leq a$ then $F(f)\equiv F(g)$ on $x\leq a.$

A quick note; I don't think this works if we want $g$ to be analytic. Consider the family of piecewise linear functions with $f_a(x) = 0$ for $x \le 0$ and $f_a(x) = ax$ otherwise. We know that the $g_a$ will all have the same Taylor series at $x = 0$, with some radius of convergence $r$. But for $a$ large enough we get $f_a(r/2) > g(r/2)$. I think the argument can be extended to show that $g$ must be nowhere analytic, which is possible, but rather pathological!

Right! Great remark! This problem is more difficult than expected.

Sounds like @BenjaminKuykendall's argument shows we can't even have g be differentiable, since if it were then the left derivative and right derivative must agree but we can make the right derivative as big as we'd like. while the left derivative is fixed

@MorA. Not sure how that follows, care to expand? That would suffice to answer this question in the negative as smooth requires differentiable.

I am not sure how to handle the case where $f(x)\to+\infty$ when $x\to-\infty,$ so I would like to start with the sub-problem of functions $f$ that are identically $0$ on the negative real axis, which seems to be the relevant case in the context that you describe.

Then, without loss of generality we may assume that $f$ is nondecreasing: otherwise apply the strategy to the historic maximum of $f$ between $0$ and $x.$

Would it help to consider strategies that are based on the values of such nondecreasing continuous $f$ on a countable dense subset of $\mathbb R^+,$ for example the nonnegative dyadic rationals?

I feel like I could answer the bounty question using the axiom of choice, but that would go against the spirit of the original question.

Proving that a strategy exists assuming transfinite induction would at least establish that we need no longer look for a counterexample. Please state your answer, mentioning its limitations, and then collect your bonus :-)

@Lieven I spent some time trying to write up a proof using the strategy I had in mind, but unfortunately I ran into a flaw in the argument that seems likely to be fatal. I'll spend a little more time on it, but I think it's likely it won't end up working.

No such mapping exists.
Our proof strategy will be to force a smooth bounding function to have unbounded derivative on a finite interval, by forcing it to be steeper and steeper on small subintervals.
Proof: Suppose there is such a mapping $m:C(\mathbb{R}^+,\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^+,\mathbb{R})$, such that $m(f)(x) > f(x)$ for all continuous $f$ and all $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$.
Let $p_0 = 1$ and $q_0 = 2$. Let $f_0(x) = 0$, and consider its mapping $m(f_0)$. Let $B = m(f_0)(1) + 1$.
We now use $p_0, q_0$, and $f_0$ as the base case to recursively define sequences of points $(p_1 < p_2 < ...)$ and $(q_1 > q_2 >...)$, and a sequence of continuous functions $(f_1,f_2,...)$, with the following properties:

$p_i < q_j$ for all $i, j \geq 0$.
$m(f_n)(p_n) < B$.
$f_n(x) \leq B$ for $x \in [0, q_n]$ and $n \geq 1$.
$\frac{d}{dx}m(f_n)(p_n) > n$ for $n \geq 1$.

The recursive construction is as follows: Choose $q_n \in \left(p_{n-1}, q_{n-1}\right)$ such that the line passing through $\left(p_{n-1}, m(f_{n-1})(p_{n-1})\right)$ and $\left(q_n, B\right)$ has slope at least $n$ (this is possible since $B > m(f_{n-1})(p_{n-1}))$. Let $f_n$ be defined as:
$$
f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
 f_{n-1}(x) \text{, for } x \in [0,p_{n-1}] \\
 l(x) \text{, for } x \in (p_{n-1}, \infty),
\end{cases}
$$
where $l(x)$ is the line passing through the points $\left(p_{n-1}, f_{n-1}(p_{n-1})\right)$ and $\left(q_n, B\right)$. Then $f_n(q_n) = B$, so $m(f_n)(q_n) > B$, thus by the Intermediate Value Theorem there is a point $c$ with $p_{n-1} < c < q_n$ such that $m(f_n)(c) = B$. By the Mean Value Theorem this means we can then find a point $p_n$ such that $p_{n-1} < p_n < c$, $m(f_n)(p_n) < B$, and
$$\frac{d}{dx}m(f_n)(p_n) = \frac{B - m(f_n)(p_{n-1})}{c - p_{n-1}} > \frac{B - m(f_{n-1})(p_{n-1})}{q_n - p_{n-1}} \geq n$$
(The first inequality holds since $q_n > c$ and $m(f_{n-1})(p_{n-1}) = m(f_n)(p_{n-1})$, and the second holds by choice of $q_n$). This completes the construction.
Since the $p_n$ are increasing and bounded from above (by any of the $q_n$), they converge; call their limit $L$. Since the functions $m(f_n)$ agree on $[0, p_n]$ for all $n$ (because the $f_n$ do), we can define $M:[0,L) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to be the function taking their common values on $[0, L)$. Similarly, we can define $F:[0,L) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to be the function taking the common values of the $f_n$.
$F(x) \leq B$ for $x \in [0,L)$ and $F$ is nondecreasing since the $f_n$ are, thus $\lim_{x \rightarrow L^-}(F(x))$ exists; call this limit $B_0$ (note that $B_0 \leq B$). In particular, we can extend $F$ to a continuous function $\bar{F}$ on $\mathbb{R}^+$ by setting $\bar{F}(x) = F(x)$ for $x < L$ and $\bar{F}(x) = B_0$ for $x \geq L$.
Consider $m(\bar{F})$. It must match $M$ on $[0, L)$, and be smooth at $L$. But
$\frac{d}{dx}M(p_n) > n$, thus $M$ has unbounded derivative on any neighborhood of $L$. This means $M$ cannot be extended to a smooth function on $[0, L]$, ie $\bar{F}$ can have no smooth mapping under $m$.$\square$
A final note: In the proof above, we only used the smoothness of a bounding function when we applied the Intermediate and Mean Value Theorems to it, and when we showed $M$ could not be extended to $L$ by continuity of the derivative. This means no such mapping exists even if we only require the bounding functions to be continuously differentiable.
